Socket screw driver with thick handle that can bend?
I used to have a tool. It was like a socket screw driver. But the handle was big and thick so I could get more leverage. But also the neck had a joint so you could bend the handle down to ~45D angle so it was kind of like holding a pistol and you could get a lot more leverage.
I lost the tool and I cannot replace it b/c I don't even know what it's called.

A breaker bar is essentially this, although usually the pivot is at the end of the shaft rather than the handle

I did a web search for “variable angle screwdriver” and found this:
https://www.amazon.com/FantastiCAR-Ratcheting-Screwdriver-Multi-function-Rotatable/dp/B0BDM2QMCX
It looks like what you described.

Oh thx a lot. The one I had was much less fancy. It had no ratchet and just straight and 45D, not various other angles. But, yes, this will do.

I don't know what your thing was called but "more leverage" is usually achieved with an ordinary socket wrench.   If there's no room for one there are close quarters ones including small socket wrenches, thumb ratchets, and gimbal ratchets.  And there are "swivel sockets" that do the bending aspect of what you describe without a handle, and can be used with a screw driver, socket wrench, or power tool.  What you had may have been some combination of these.
